# How to format argument date in older FreeBSD?

Tags: shell, date, freebsd

I have a function that receives date as an argument and I need to format it so it would work on older FreeBSD on our school server.

```
selected_date=$(date -j $1 +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

This is what I have so far. Could someone advise me how to correct it so it would work?

Comment: What date format do you receive in `$1` (ie, please provide sample input)? What error is `date` giving you when called this way? What version of FreeBSD are you running? Is upgrading an option?

Comment: There should be a `-f` format for specifying what format to expect from `$1` (which should be quoted).

Answer (score 0):

The Code has not change in the last FreeBSD releases.

- Make sure your input argument is quoted.
- use option -f to specify the date format of your input
- if you have non numeric input data, ensure the locale is set.

Example, tested on FreeBSD 8.4 and FreeBSD 11.1:

```
env LANG=C date -j -f '%b %d %T %Z %Y' 'Dec 24 02:12:21 CET 2016' '+%Y-%m-%d'
```